# AVAudioSession background mode problem

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudiosession

I have set up my AVAudioSession to play music in the background

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];
if (setCategoryError) {
}

NSError *activationError = nil;
[audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError];
if (activationError) { 
}
```

Also added 'Required background modes' in my plist file.

When I play a remote file and the iPhone enters the background the audio keeps playing as suspected. But when I play a song from the iPod inside my app (MPMediaItem URL) it won't continue to play in the background.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not missing anything. When the user starts playing music from iPod, it will stop your app from playing any further audio.

If you mean something else, please leave a note and I'll update this answer.

**Edit:** You should start iPod music by setting the queue on the relevant instance of `MPMusicPlayerController`, and then sending it the `-play` message. If you use the URL provided by the `MPMediaItem` object with an `AVAudioPlayer` instance or similar, it will be routed differently and may not be able to continue playing in the background.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. My app plays remote files as local ipod music as well (MPMediaItem URL). When I start a song from the ipod it wont play in background. Thanks!

Comment: Ok thanks, that points me in the good direction. But currently I am using a MPMoviePlayerController to easily play the remote files. What would be the best way to allow a user to play local iPod music as remote files (wich can be selected from a playlist) as well? Thanks!